# php ajax works, and doesn't work

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

HTML

```
echo '<form id="f_'.$id.'" method="post">';
echo '<input type="hidden" name="re_ti" value="'.$ti.'">';
echo '</form>';
echo '<button id="rBtn" l="#f_'.$id.'" class="button_accept" onclick="document.getElementById(\'review\').style.display = \'block\';">Review</button>';
```

AJAX

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#rBtn').click(function() {
     var log = $(this).attr("l");
     alert(l);
     $.ajax({
           type:"post",
           url:"php_parsers/review.php",
           data: $(l).serialize(),
           success: function(response){
               $("#reviewMain").html(response);
           }
     });
     $.ajax({
           type:"post",
           url:"php_parsers/comment.php",
           data: $(l).serialize(),
           success: function(response){
               $("#reviewSub").html(response);
           }
     });
  });
});
```

So the HTML code is echoed with PHP, and each form has a different id.
Example form id is `#f_234324`  (it is the count).

The forms are echoed using `while`, and everything works find if there is only one echoed, but my Ajax does not work if there is more then one form echoed.

The Ajax should get `l` and use `l` to change the data: to the forum I want.

If someone knows a better way to explain it please let me know. The alert pops up if there is one form, but not if there are two.

What am I missing?

Comment: nice title though :p

Comment: Sorry i ment to go back and change it.

Comment: @DillonBurnett, Can you simply post multiple forms instead of `php echo` code ? That will help us understand the issue..

Comment: Change identifier in js ie $('#rBtn') to $('.button_accept'). As id will point one not multiple use class name as identifier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is, that you've got more than one `rBtn` id in your document, because if the while loop in php makes more than one button, you've got more than one id `rBtn`. You should use an id unique. I would use the class name in the selector:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.button_accept').click(function() {
     var log = $(this).attr("l");
     alert(l);
     $.ajax({
           type:"post",
           url:"php_parsers/review.php",
           data: $(l).serialize(),
           success: function(response){
               $("#reviewMain").html(response);
           }
     });
     $.ajax({
           type:"post",
           url:"php_parsers/comment.php",
           data: $(l).serialize(),
           success: function(response){
               $("#reviewSub").html(response);
           }
     });
  });
});
```

So the click event handler is set on all elements with the class `button_accept` and `$(this)` will return the clicked button on click. I hope that could solve your problem.

**By the way**, you should name your `l` attribute to `data-l` to write valid html5 code. The button element doesn't have an attribute `l` and the namespace `data-*` names your own (new) attributes.

Comment: exactly, what `#rBtn` will do is trigger click event only for your first form.

Comment: i have actually tried to use the class first and it did not work.  But for some reason i changed the class to "buttonaccept" and it works.

Why the "_" does not let it work... i have no idea.

Thanks for the help Harsh Makani!